# Scroll to right of div

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, chat

I am creating a chat using Ajax requests and I'm trying to get messages div to scroll to the right without much luck.

I am wrapping everything in this div:

```css
#scroll {
  width: 500px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Is there a way to keep it scrolled to the right by default using JS?

Is there a way to keep it scrolled to the right after an ajax request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Scroll to right of container
const container = document.querySelector('.container')
container.scrollLeft = container.scrollWidth
```